# I had asked a question on stack overflow, and it is solved now but am wondering how some of the answerers got this information?

Tags: discussion

This is the link to the question, which is now solved and closed. I wrote a comment about some of the info provided, but since it's closed not sure it will get answers. I was wondering how Jakub Konecki was able to get that ReferenceError, I didn't get that, but it would have been helpful. Also how to check if the jsfiddle has been tried like Karoly has mentioned? Thank you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217139/error-please-use-post-request

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the technical reasons someone was able to answer a specific question, not about anything about Stack Overflow or the Stack Exchange network itself.

Comment: On an unrelated note, when posting a question you shouldn't just post a fiddle link alone; it's important that the question itself have enough information for people to answer it.  The fiddle link can be posted *in addition to* the actual code, just not *instead of* your code.  You were probably told this in a system message when you tried to post your question the first time, which is why you had to post the fiddle as text and not as a link.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about $Topic, within the scope defined in the [help].

Comment: Eeek.  It's going to take awhile to get used to the new closing system.

Comment: @RobertHarvey What's $Topic?

Comment: $Topic is a variable which depends on the mood of the moderator.

Comment: @static It's a "donut hole" variable that managed to sneak its way into a comment, when it was copied from my custom close reason. It translated properly in the banner below, but not in the comment.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ahh, it 's just it didn't look like a markup mistake... I do like the idea of a "does not appear to be about [How do I feel like closing today]" close reason prompt though...

Answer (score 3):

You should post a comment on your question to respond to the comments of those users.  Prefix your comment with @ to ensure that they're notified of your comment.

Closing a question does not prevent additional comments from being posted.

Comment: Note, however that that person may decide to not respond. As is their right.

Comment: @Oded Of course.  (In retrospect, I missed an opportunity to demonstrate your point by responding.)